Android - Two Queues for Sync requests using workmanager
Problem Statement -
What ?  - Create two(multiple) sync queues one for longer operations(e.g file uploads/downloads) another for for rest of the sync data with smaller HTTP requests
Why ?  - Large number of longer operations (file uploads/ downloads) should not throttle rest of the quick and easy Sync operations
Exploring ways to achieve this in Android using WorkManager. (Threadpools ?)
Reference - https://www.atlassian.com/engineering/sync-offline-attachments
